# How to provide components from a library, for consumption by multiple DI frameworks

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, guice

My team owns a library that provides components that must be referencable by code that consumes the library. Some of our consumers use Spring to instantiate their apps; others use Guice. We'd like some feedback on best-practices on how to provide these components. Two options that present themselves are:

1. Have our library provide a Spring `Configuration` that consumers can `@Import`, and a Guice `Module` that they can `install`.
2. Have our library provide a `ComponentProvider` singleton, which provides methods to fetch the relevant components the library provides.

Quick sketches of what these would look like:

### Present in both approaches

```java
// In their code
@AllArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Inject))
public class ConsumingClass {
  private final FooDependency foo;
  ...
}
```

### First approach

```java
// In our code
@Configuration
public class LibraryConfiguration {
  @Bean public FooDependency foo() {...}
  ...
}

---

public class LibraryModule extends AbstractModule {
  @Provides FooDependency foo() {...}
  ...
}

========================
========================

// In their code
@Configuration
@Import(LibraryConfiguration.java)
public class ConsumerConfiguration {
  // Whatever initiation logic they want - but, crucially, does
  // *not* need to define a FooDependency
 ...
}

---

// *OR*
public class ConsumerModule extends AbstractModule {
  @Override
  public void configure() {
    // Or, simply specify LibraryModule when creating the injector
    install(new LibraryModule());
    ...
    // As above, no requirement to define a FooDependency
  }
}
```

### Second approach

```java
// In our code
public class LibraryProvider {
  public static final INSTANCE = buildInstance();
  private static LibraryProvider buildInstance() {...}
  private static LibraryProvider getInstance() {return INSTANCE;}
}

========================
========================

// In their code
@Configuration
public class ConsumerConfiguration {
  @Bean public FooDependency foo() {
    return LibraryProvider.getInstance().getFoo();
  }
  ...
}
// or equivalent for Guice
```

Is there an accepted Best Practice for this situation? If not, what are some pros and cons of each, or of another option I haven't yet thought of? The first approach has the advantage that consumers don't need to write any code to initialize dependencies, and that DI frameworks can override dependencies (e.g. with mocked dependencies for testing); whereas the second approach has the advantage of being DI-framework agnostic (if a new consumer wanted to use Dagger to instantiate their app, for instance, we wouldn't need to change the library at all)

Answer (score 0):

I think the first option is better. If your library has inter-dependencies between beans then the code of `@Configuration` in case of spring in the second approach) will be:

1. Fragile (what if application doesn't know that a certain bean should be created)
2. Duplicated - this code will appear in each and every consumer's module
3. When the new version of your library gets released and a consumer wants to upgrade- there might be changes in consumer's configuration ( the lib might expose a new bean, deprecate or even remove some old stuff, etc.)

One small suggestion:

You can use Spring factories and then you don't even need to make an `@Import` in case of spring boot. just add a maven dependency and it will load the configuration automatically.

Now, make sure that you work correctly with dependencies in case of that approach.
Since you code will include both spring and Juice dependent code, you'll add dependencies on both for your maven/gradle module of the library. This means, that consumer that uses, say, guice, will get all the spring stuff because of your library. There are many ways to overcome this issue depending on the build system of your choice, just want wanted to bring it up

Comment: Appreciate the response, thanks! We're actually using an in-house build system, so "maven dependencies" aren't relevant - but we'll look into Spring factories to advise consumers on how to consume. As for our consumers getting both Spring and Guice dependencies when taking a dependency on us - duly noted, thanks, but our build system has ways to exclude unnecessary dependencies, so there should be way to work-around.